# Is there a way to force the keyboard to be numeric using InputMethodManager?

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is show the keyboard with the following code

```
InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
input.showSoftInput(view, 0);
```

But it only ever displays the standard keyboard. I'm wondering if there is a simple command like.

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

That will show the number pad.
I've read everything I can find but all of the answers point to editing the input field or some variation. I've looked into the documentation about SetInputMethod and SetInputMethodSubtype but couldn't find any examples that did what I wanted.

I just was to be able to tell the input what keyboard to show.

Thanks

Comment: you need to set inputtype to your edittext editPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); check if it works

Comment: I don't have an edit text. I'm using a webview

Answer (score 1):

Set the inputType of the text field to be number in XML.  That will tell the keyboard that you want a numeric keyboard.  That doesn't force it to show a numeric keyboard, but it tell the keyboard you want it to, and it should be honored if that keyboard has a numeric keyboard.